# ruby File.join(dir, "**", "*")

Tags: ruby, file

Let's consider the following code chunk:

```
 def remove_symlinks
   @blobs_dir="/tmp"
   Dir[File.join(@blobs_dir, "**", "*")].each do |file|
     FileUtils.rm_rf(file) if File.symlink?(file)
   end
 end
```

I feel confused about this line:

```
File.join(@blobs_dir, "**", "*")
```

I don't know what it means, especially the `"**"` and `"*"`.

Comment: Why some many people always interested in editing others' questions and answers?

Comment: to make them grammatically correct, for starters.

Comment: Why some many people ... => Why are so many people ...

Comment: Interesting word game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File.join(@blobs_dir, "**", "*")
```

means it will generate a new string by joining the strings using File::SEPARATOR. Please refer to [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-join).

Here, it will generate a path like /tmp/**/ * .

```
Dir[File.join(@blobs_dir, "**", "*")]
```

** means to match directories recursively. * will match all files. Please refer to [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D)

So it looks like this code is to check all files under all sub-directories of /tmp to find symbol links and delete them.